# Direct way of listplotting each 2 or 3 points?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of points

```
myList={{x_1,y_1},{x_2,y_2},...,{x_n,y_n}}
```

I want to plot not all the points of this list but to plot every $k$ points. For example, if I wanted to plot every $k=2$ points, the plot will contain only the points:

```
{{x_1,y_1},{x_3,y_3},{x_5,y_5},...}
```

or

```
{{x_2,y_2},{x_4,y_4},...}
```

It doesn't matter if Mathematica plots the odd points or the even points.

Another example is if I wanted to plot every $k=3$ points, the plot would contain only

```
{{x_1,y_1},{x_4,y_4},{x_7,y_7},...}
```

**Question.** Is there a direct way of doing this in Mathematica, without creating manually another list from `myList`?

Comment: Look up `Downsample[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Part` (also written `[[...]]`) to get what you want.
For example,

```
myList= Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, 20}];

ListPlot[myList]
ListPlot[myList[[1;;-1;;2]]] (* every second point *)
ListPlot[myList[[1;;-1;;3]]] (* every 3rd point*)
```

Comment: Or simply, `ListPlot[myList[[;; ;;2]]]` or `ListPlot[myList[[;; ;;3]]]`. The `1` and `-1` are default values and are not required.

Answer (score 4):

The ways listed work perfectly well, but you can save yourself a couple of keystrokes just by doing

```
myList[[;;;;2]]
```

If you don't provide starting and ending points for the first `;;`, Mathematica is kind enough to assume that you want to go from the beginning (`1`) to the end (`-1`). For my tastes, at least, this looks a little nicer too. (It'll auto-format inside the program in a way that makes it a little easier to read than it's rendered here:)

[image]